# Generate Video from Images on the fly?

Tags: video

I was wondering if anyone out there had any information about creating videos on the fly.  I did find FFmpg and Dvd-Slidshow that when used together they will create the video and effects that im looking for.  This is an example of a video that I would like to create (http://animoto.com/pro/real-estate).  Other than the top two options is there anything else that anyone has tried out that worked really well?  Has anyone used a third party to "push" images to an api that creates the videos on the fly?

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's an API to do so :you can use the Stupeflix API to do server side video renderings, using After Effects templates or built-in effects. Find it at http://developer.stupeflix.com/documentation, with a lot of other tools to do image / video processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Templater Bot](http://dcly.io/templater-bot-aes) from Dataclay to do this.  It is built atop After Effects.  You prepare an AE template with Templater and then its ready to be versioned by data that comes in from your data source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Publitio to generate video from image on the fly https://publit.io/community/blog/on-the-fly-video-and-image-processing

Once you upload images to publit.io it is simple as changing extension of image from jpg to mp4

Sample image

```
https://media.publit.io/file/butterflies.jpg
```

Image to Video conversion

```
https://media.publit.io/file/butterflies.mp4
```

More on subject here https://publit.io/docs/#transcoding